# IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/11/delete/ FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

when i delete user from my admin panel it shows me given error I dont understand what is the reason of this error or where i am making mistake. I can update and create new users and delete those user who dont have profile but the users which have profiles they are unable to delete because of the following here which i given below.
[image]

accounts/models.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
from PIL import Image
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Profile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        avatar = models.ImageField(default='1.jpg', upload_to='displays', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
    
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs) #it will take data and save it

        dp = Image.open(self.avatar.path) #storing avatar in variable
        if dp.height >300 or dp.width >300:
            output_size =(300,300) #set any size you want
            dp.thumbnail(output_size) 
            dp.save(self.avatar.path) #after resizing it save it in data base in place of uploaded once by user
 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Profile_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

accounts/forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    from django.core import validators
    
    User = get_user_model()
    
    class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    
        class Meta:
            fields = ["username","email","password1","password2"]
            model = get_user_model()
            widgets ={
                'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass','placeholder':'username'}),
            }
        
        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Email is invalid")
            return email
        
    
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
            # self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

accounts/views.py

```
user = User
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid:
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            send_mail(
            'i gotch you',
            'how are uou',
            'coolahmed21@hgmail.com',
            [email],
            fail_silently=False,
            )
        return super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the on_delete=CASCADE . That means that if the object to which the ForeignKey refers is deleted, then it should delete the referring object as well. Such CASCADE can thus result in a large amount of objects that get deleted, since the deletion of objects can in fact trigger other deletes, and so on.

Try this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User, null=True on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `post_save`, `post_delete` to `pre_save` and `pre_delete` and it will work just fine.